# Is onCreate() called before onStart() if onStart() is called after onRestart()?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer, android-resources, android-lifecycle

I don't understand that when I release the `MediaPlayer` obj's resources using the `release()` method in the `onStop()` method when I resume the activity, why can the `MediaPlayer` still play the sound after I click the play button even when the obj was released in the `onStop()` method and I am sure that the `onStop()` method is called. So what might be the reason for this to happen, is the `onCreate()` method called as soon as the `onRestart()` method calls the `onStart()` method or is there any other reason for it?

My logic is that if in the `onStop()` method I release the `MediaPlayer` obj's resources then there should be no instance in the obj that holds the audio file in it so when the activity is resumed no audio shall be played as the obj is assigned a *null* value in the `releaseMediaPlayerResources()` method after its resources are released so which is why I think for the obj to get an instance the `onCreate()` must be called as that is the method in which I have assigned the `MediaPlayer` obj an audio file.

```
private MediaPlayer audio;
private Button playBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_list_view);
    playBtn = findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
        
    playBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                releaseMediaPlayerResources();
                audio = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
                audio.start();
            }
    });

}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    releaseMediaPlayerResources();
    Toast.makeText(this, "onStop() releasing res...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void releaseMediaPlayerResources() {
    if(audio!=null){
        audio.release();
        audio = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why can the MediaPlayer still play the sound after I click the play button even when the obj was released in the onStop() method?

Because on each button click you first release the `MediaPlayer` and then create a new instance of it and start:

```
releaseMediaPlayerResources();
audio = MediaPlayer.create(YourActivity.this, R.raw.song);
audio.start();
```

> is the onCreate() method called as soon as the onRestart() method calls the onStart() method?

[No](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle).

Answer (score 2):

**Refer to this image , it always helped me when I am wondering what function is called when?** 
[image: Android Activity Lifecycle]

Comment: Not sure how this ended up in the very low quality queue, this is a useful diagram. +1 and "looks ok" from me on this one.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica I am guessing *"This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content."*... Looks OK to me as well